# How can I easily convert a Django app from mySQL to PostgreSQL?

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

Has anyone done this? Is it an easy process?  We're thinking of switching over for transactions and because mysql seems to be "crapping out" lately.

Comment: 1) MySql does support transactions (InnoDB) 2) What makes you think MySql is "crapping out" lately?

Comment: For now reason we'll just start getting tones of these errors:  OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')  Also, using South with Django sometimes hurts without real transactions.

Comment: MySQL doesn't support schema transactions - which can cause a massive headache for migrations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used this tool to migrate an internal app and it worked wonderfully. https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres

Answer (score 35):

Converting MySQL database to Postgres database with Django

First backup your data of the old Mysql database in json fixtures:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata contenttypes --indent=4 --natural-foreign > contenttype.json
$ python manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes --indent=4 --natural-foreign > everything_else.json
```

Then switch your settings.DATABASES to postgres settings.

Create the tables in Postgresql:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Now delete all the content that is automatically made in the migrate (django contenttypes, usergroups etc):

```
$ python manage.py sqlflush | ./manage.py dbshell
```

And now you can safely import everything, and keep your pk's the same!

```
$ python manage.py loaddata contenttype.json
$ python manage.py loaddata everything_else.json
```

Tested with Django==1.8

Comment: Worked perfectly for me with Django==1.11.4

Comment: OMG You saved my day... I've been trying to move my data from MySQL to PGSQL over the weekend with pdloader. The tool always gives me a weird error that I don't even know how to start debugging... Your way is just fantastic. Thanks a lot and your answer should be the accepted one!

Comment: Thanks! I also has success here with my django project, but was getting duplicate `PK` key errors until I commented out all my `post_save.connect()` callbacks (which were creating additional entries).

Comment: Also works great for moving data from PGSQL to MySQL! Didn't work in one fixture before...Django 3.2... Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using Django serializers to output the data from MySQL's format into JSON and then back into Postgres. There are some good artices on internet about that:

[Migrating Django from MySQL to PostgreSQL the Easy Way](http://www.ofbrooklyn.com/2010/07/18/migrating-django-mysql-postgresql-easy-way/)

[Move a Django site to PostgreSQL: check](http://zerokspot.com/weblog/2008/07/26/move-a-django-site-to-postgresql-check/)

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it personally, but it seems like a combination of the [dumpdata](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) and [loaddata](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) options of manage.py would be able to solve your problem quite easily. That is, unless you have a lot of database-specific things living outside the ORM such as stored procedures.

Comment: that work, but sometime there are need truncate all tables just created by syncdb

Comment: dump data loads the entire dataset into memoery before serializing it - this is a problem for a large data set.  http://www.ofbrooklyn.com/2010/07/18/migrating-django-mysql-postgresql-easy-way/ shows how to chunk this process to avoid crashing your server.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done it either.
I'd first follow this [migration guide, there is a MySql section](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL) which should take care of all your data. Then django just switch the mysql to postgre in the settings. I think that should be ok.

I found another question on stackoverflow which should help with the converting mysql to postgre [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717/migrating-from-mysql-to-postgresql).

Answer (score 0):

1. python manage.py dump.data >> data.json
2. Create database and user in postrgesql
3. Set your just created database in postrgesql as default database in django settings or use param --database=your_postrgesql_database next steps
4. Run syncdb for create tables.

   python syncdb [--database=your_postrgesql_database] --noinput
5. Create dump without data, drop all tables and load dump. Or truncate all tables (table django_content_type whith data which can be not equals your old data - it is way to many errors). At this step we need empty tables in postgresql-db.
6. When you have empty tables in postgresql-db just load your data:

   python manage.py loaddata data.json

And be fun!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Django management command that copies one database to another:
https://gist.github.com/mturilin/1ed9763ab4aa98516a7d

You need to add both database in the settings and use this command:

```
./manage.py copy_db from_database to_database app1 app2 app3 --delete --ignore-errors
```

What cool about this command is that it recursively copy dependent objects. For example, if the model have 2 foreign keys and two Many-to-Many relationships, it will copy the other objects first to ensure you won't get foreign key violation error.

Comment: broken git link

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this exercise and the answer provided by [michael-van-de-waeter](https://@https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514427/michael-van-de-waeter) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30129025/7493724) is perfect.

However, I would like to add the following needed steps:

1. I had to first delete ContentType following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64669161/7493724):

`python manage.py shell`

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

ContentType.objects.all().delete()
```

2. I had also to append a square bracket to the data json:

   `echo ']' >> everything_else.json`