# Python manage.py dumpdata killed prematurely

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm migrating a database from MySQL to Postgres. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964615/how-can-i-easily-convert-a-django-app-from-mysql-to-postgresql) has been very helpful. When running the `python manage.py dumpdata --exclude contenttypes --indent=4 --natural-foreign > everything_else.json` to create a json fixture the connection is aborted by the database server. All other steps have been successful.

The MySQL database is hosted on RDS and the connection is aborted at the same point in the file each time I try to run this (file size is always 12288 bytes). Logs from the RDS instance state the problem as follows (db, user and host changed to dummy values):

```
[Note] Aborted connection 600000 to db: 'mydb' user: 'myUsername' host: '127.0.0.1' (Got an error writing communication packets)
```

In the terminal the message is simply `killed`.

Why would this error be happening and how can I create this json fixture?

**Update**
To test for timeout issues I've followed the advice in [this post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-communication-packet-error/) to change default timeout values. This has no effect on the problem.

I've also tried modifying the DB instance to one with more memory etc. This had no effect.

**Further update**
I didn't get to the bottom of this but instead took a different route and used AWS database migration service (DMS). There's a good walkthrough for this [here](https://www.workfall.com/learning/blog/how-to-migrate-rds-mysql-database-to-rds-postgresql-database-using-aws-database-migration-servicedms/). For my small ~5GB database the migration process took 5 minutes with negligible costs on the smallest DMS instance.

Comment: "At the same point in the file" > Have you tried with other files to make sure the issue isn't a query timeout or something?

Comment: Creating the fixtures for the data types (python manage.py dumpdata contenttypes --indent=4 --natural-foreign > contenttype.json) worked without a problem but this will necessarily create a much smaller file. If it IS a timeout issue is there some way to force RDS to keep the connection open?

Comment: The host is never the loopback interface when connecting to a remote RDS instance, are you really getting "host: '127.0.0.1'"? If so this might indicate a timeout and some sort of fallback from the specified mysql host address.

Comment: No, as mentioned in the question I put in dummy values for the db user and host

Comment: So if it works with a smaller file like you said, and the timeout isn't the problem, have you tried upping the `max_allowed_packet` like the linked article recommends?

Comment: I think `dumpdata` might be running out of memory if it gets `Killed`. Check the server's `dmesg` logs.

Comment: @AaronMeese Yes, I've upped the max_allowed_packet to just under the max. It didn't help.

Comment: @AKX How can I view the `dmesg` logs on RDS? I can view the running error logs and keep getting th esame error (as posted in the question)

Comment: No, I mean the instance running the dump command.